# CompactFlash driver for Sony Clié (Palm OS)

Tags: driver, sony, palm, clie

A Sony Clié ([PEG-NX70V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_CLI%C3%89_PEG-NX70V)) has come into my possession. It runs Palm OS 5.0, and has both a MemoryStick slot and a CompactFlash slot. The latter is only designed for use with a WiFi card, as Sony expected people would use their proprietary MemorySticks for data storage instead.

A third party, EruWare, [wrote a driver](http://www.palminfocenter.com/view_story.asp?ID=5276) that added support for CF cards for the PEG-NX70V (and other models) in 2003. This company seemed to fragment in two later that year (according to [this blog post](https://technofile.blogspot.com/2003/10/things-change-fast-its-technology-or.html)), resulting in two companies which each sold a CF driver for the Clié range: Athena's [CF Enabler](https://web.archive.org/web/20040604071923/http://www.athenaamerica.com/aa_proddetail.asp?prod=cfstoragedriver) and PDAscent's [CF Magic](https://web.archive.org/web/20040730145912/http://www.pdascent.com/). Both these websites have long since disappeared from the internet, leaving only a skeletal presence on archive.org as testament that they once existed.

There was also a free driver written by "Pelaca", which patched the relevant OS files to use the Cf slot. These were hosted at [snow.prohosting.com/~cfutil/](https://web.archive.org/web/20031216025711/http://snow.prohosting.com/~cfutil/) (later [snow.prohosting.com/cfutil/](https://web.archive.org/web/20030803213240/http://snow.prohosting.com:80/cfutil/)) which again only exist at archive.org now. Sadly, while some binary files were archived, the relevant one (CFUtility) wasn't.

(There's also a patching utility by "Mini" that *was* [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20071008155024/http://usagiya.g-com.ne.jp/mini/mp/minipatchEN.htm), but it is only designed for the NX80, so is of no use to me.)

**Is there a copy of any of these drivers still in existence? Or is there an alternative driver that may work for my NX70?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archive.org has a copy of Clié files that Rich Legg [mirrored on his website](https://web.archive.org/web/20081002212831/http://leggnet.com:80/clie/). These include a file by the name of CFUtilityPelaca0603.zip, which appears to be a June 2003 version of Pelaca's CFUtility (1.0.3). There are also a number of other Clié-related files there.

CFUtility is provided as a .exe file, and requires Palm Desktop to be installed on the system. It uses Palm Desktop's HotSync function to install itself to the Clié device. I found that installation worked fine using Palm Desktop 6.2 on Windows XP (32-bit).